# Declaring multiple arrays in Julia

Tags: arrays, julia

Suppose I need to declare (but not initialize the values of) five 10x10 arrays, named, say, `A1`-`A5`. Fortran has a nice syntax for this kind of multiple array declaration:

```
REAL(8), DIMENSION(10,10) :: A1, A2, A3, A4, A5
```

However, the only method in Julia I am aware of is much uglier:

```
A1 = Array(Float64, 10, 10)
A2 = Array(Float64, 10, 10)
A3 = Array(Float64, 10, 10)
A4 = Array(Float64, 10, 10)
A5 = Array(Float64, 10, 10)
```

Is there any more concise way to declare multiple arrays of the same dimension in Julia?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks to some help from @simonster in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26071317/declaring-top-level-variables-in-julia-using-metaprogramming) you can succinctly declare your variables without any runtime overhead using metaprogramming,

```
for x = [:A1,:A2,:A3,:A4,:A5]
    @eval $x = Array(Float64,10,10)
end
```

However, we can now do one step better than Fortran by allowing you to generate the names dynamically as well:

```
for x in [symbol("A"*string(i)) for i=1:100]
    @eval $x = Array(Float64,10,10)
end
```

This will allocate 100 arrays A1-A100. Thanks to @rickhf12hs's comment for this idea/implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the thanks!  8-) Thanks to @simonster for getting us started.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's ok to create one temporary array holding the resulting five arrays, you could use an array comprehension:

```
A1, A2, A3, A4, A5 = [Array(Float64, 10, 10) for i = 1:5]
```